# I want to Automate saving all characters of a font in Photoshop

Tags: fonts, adobe-photoshop, photoshop-cs5

So I have a square Photoshop document, containing 1-character text from a font I like, and with special effects (drop shadow, emboss, etc...).

The manual way is I type a character, then save a PNG. I have to repeat this for the other characters.

How can I automate saving the letters A-Z, a-z, and 0-9 using actions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really do it using actions. But you can definitely do it with Adobe Extendscript.  It's not too tough if you've ever messed with JavaScript.
Check out a tutorial here: http://morris-photographics.com/photoshop/tutorials/scripting1.html

Alternatively, you can just type out all the characters you need into a large horizontal canvas, and divide the image with slices, and save them all at once with Save for Web.

Comment: Hi Matt! As of this writing I already found the solution for this. And it's Adobe ExtendScript (same with your answer). Thanks! :)